# how to calculate totals and minimum spanning trees using arrays

Tags: c#, count, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm working on a C# assignment in which i have to create a minimum spanning tree through the use of arrays. My code is made up of three arrays which track the nodes and whether or not they have been reached. I have to find the smallest total for all of the randomly generated links to be added up to visit all of the nodes. However, for some reason it is not quite working. The totals being produced are not correct and just wondered if anyone could help me work out why.I believe the error must be between the calculating of the total or how the minimum value is being decided or possible both however i am unsure.

So far i have tried changing the way it is calculated to involve a sum variable to store the values seperately. Ive attempted to add another if statement that would stop the min value from being anything above 98 ( the void value is 99) i have also tried to alter the earlier code to see if how i am testing the values in the SP array are the desired ones. still no results

```
            int n = 5;              //n = number of values
        int m = 50;             //m = max value in arra
        int VoidValue = 99;     // if i = j value = void value
        int Total = 0;          //Total value for spanning tree
        int sum = 0;        //Sum for total value for spanning tree

        Random Rand = new Random(); //Create randomise value


        int[,] c = new int[n + 1, n + 1]; //Cost array

        int[] SP = new int[n + 1];      //Spanned array

        int[,] AD = new int[n + 1, n + 1];  //Adjacency array

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            SP[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {

                if (i == j)
                {
                    c[i, j] = VoidValue;               // give void spaces the value of 99
                    AD[i, j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    c[i, j] = Rand.Next(1, m);    // Populate the array with randomised values
                    AD[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        //Output all arrays to screen

        Console.WriteLine("Cost Array: At the beginning");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    Console.Write("c[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + "- " + " ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("c[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + c[i, j].ToString("00") + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Spanned Array : At the beginning");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("S[" + i + "] = " + SP[i].ToString("00") + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Adjacency Array : At the beginning");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    Console.Write("A[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + "- " + " ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("A[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + AD[i, j].ToString("00") + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Random Starting Point

        int startPoint = Rand.Next(1, n + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Start at node " + startPoint);
        SP[startPoint] = 1;

        //Check the spanned array 
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Spanned Array : After the starting point has been chosen ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("S[" + i + "] = " + SP[i].ToString("00") + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Find minimum vallue link, repeatedly follow these links until spanned array is full

        for (int p = 1; p < n; p++) // For every value of the spanned array 
        {
            int MinValue = VoidValue, MinValuei = 0, MinValuej = 0; // declare variables
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)        // I and J are for both variables of the cost and adjacent array
                    if (i != j)
                    {
                        if (SP[i] == 1)             //Spanned node
                        {
                            if (SP[j] == 0)         //Unspanned node
                            {
                                if (c[i, j] < MinValue)
                                {

                                  MinValue = c[i, j];
                                  MinValuei = i;
                                  MinValuej = j;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                AD[MinValuei, MinValuej] = 1;
                SP[MinValuej] = 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("The min value is: " + MinValue);
            Total = Total + MinValue;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("The total is: " + Total);
        }
        //Finally output spanned and adjacent arrays 

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Spanned Array: After spanning tree");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("S[" + i + "] = " + SP[i].ToString("00") + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Adjacency Array : After spanning tree");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    Console.Write("A[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + "- " + " ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("A[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + AD[i, j].ToString("00") + " ");
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        //Output total value for the spanning tree

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("The total value for the spanning tree: " + Total);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. What has your own research uncovered? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: So far what i have discovered is that for some reason the 5th and final min value always 99. Not too sure as to why as it should be finding the min value and that clearly is not it. also i have found in one of my tests that the minimum spanning tree algorithm has returned to a node that was already reached. Not too sure why this was it may have just been an error in my code at the time that just happened once. The min value is automatically set to 99 to begin the search so maybe it is possible it isnt testing the final min value and therefore just displaying the value  it starts as.

Comment: This is the sort of detail that should be in the body of the question. Remember that SO is not a threaded forum, and comments are not really part of the Q&A. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. At the end of the day, you have some code that you wrote that is not working in some manner. This isn't really a question...

Comment: You can see these issues yourself if you run the code. I have added extra write lines to display the totals and minimum values after each loop and you can see the issue is pronounced.

Comment: Assume that few are going to run the code without seeing that you have demonstrated that you have done the basics. Have you debugged into the code for the cases where you expect different results? Have you asserted that your assumptions line by line are correct? Make sure you take the [tour] and get a feel for how SO works. Questions that are a blob of code that you want us to run and debug won't get much traction here, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm still new to C# so not too sure how to do this

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio, that has an excellent debugger available to you. Otherwise, continue doing what you are doing with console logging, but really pay attention to the flow of the logic. Test _every_ single one of your assertions.

Comment: I am using visual studios so how do i go about using the debugger to solve this issue? or would you suggest just watching videos online for tutorials

Comment: Yeah, SO is not great for tutorials. This is one of those cases where you just have to bite the bullet and learn it, either just by doing it or by doing some homework tutorials. One the easiest ways to get started is just step through your code where you think things are going wrong and inspect each and every variable and make sure you understand why things are changing as they do. Never assume that a line of code is doing what you think until you prove it. Especially as a beginner, some things can surprise you.

Comment: I know for definite that my arrays are all being created correctly. I also know that they are being populated correctly. The part I am finding difficult is my minimum spanning tree coding part. So where I have my multiple for loops and if statements which search for the minimum value and change the other arrays according.

Comment: BTW, I cannot recommend talking to a rubber duck (see my first link) enough. Using SO as a rubber duck is fine, but you don't get the immediate feedback as you do from your very own duck sitting on your desk. Alternatively, you can use a real life colleague. We've all been relegated to rubber duck at some point.

Comment: This is why a debugger will help clarify the logic, especially when you have a lot of branches. This is something that is really hard to grok by reading, when a single missed inverted boolean can throw your assumptions into question.

Comment: As an aside, this is one of those cases that illustrates why I think that instructors should _start_ with how to use editors, IDEs and debuggers **first** before having you run off and write some code that implements a specific algorithm. I always feel like we don't give beginners the tools they need to succeed.

Comment: I was kind of thrown in the deep end by my teacher and left to it so its kinda difficult to grasp

Comment: My last advice: work from the known to the unknown. You know your arrays are sound, and you suspect your algorithm that uses some tricky logic. Debugging code is like the "fog of war" in a game. Assume nothing about some code until you have exercised it and turned it into a known. Otherwise it is unknown, and the entire thing could be one chunk of "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Final final advice: remember that your instructor is there for you for this stuff. He or she has something in mind when they gave the assignment, and it will be exceedingly clear to them if you get some solution from the unwashed internet. You should feel free to raise your questions with your instructor.

Comment: I managed to fix it and get it working. Thanks for the help anyway! @jdv